# how to enable smooth horizontal scrolling on android in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am currently debugging a Flutter app on a mobile phone, and I am experiencing an issue with horizontal scrolling. The problem is that I can only drag the `SizeBox` sideways, but when I release my finger from the screen, the `SizeBox` returns to its original state where only half of the content is visible. Consequently, I cannot scroll smoothly on an Android phone. I haven't had the opportunity to test it on an iPhone yet.
**i've tried `ListView`**

```
class WeekView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeekView({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeekView> createState() => _WeekViewState();
}

class _WeekViewState extends State<WeekView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
            child: SfCalendar(
                 view: CalendarView.workWeek,
                 showDatePickerButton: true,
                  ...
...
```

**I've also tried `SingleChildScrollView`**

```
class WeekView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeekView({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeekView> createState() => _WeekViewState();
}

class _WeekViewState extends State<WeekView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
        child: SfCalendar(
          
          view: CalendarView.workWeek,
          showDatePickerButton: true,
```

Also,I removed the `SizedBox` and adjusted the SfCalender settings as below but its now working either

```
 timeSlotViewSettings: const TimeSlotViewSettings(
              timeInterval: Duration(hours: 1),
              timeIntervalWidth: 200,
              timeIntervalHeight: 50,
```